# Show actual db connection

Tags: php, database, connection

I need to return the actual text description of the db connection, and any other relevant info about the DB.

Why? I call a service and the expected data comes back perfectly.

Now, when I do the same call inside of a secure tunnel, I get completely different results.

All indications say that the code is working in both cases.

So, I can only imagine that it's hooking up to a different DB...
So...I would like to have the function return the server name and the actual db being queried against - even the path where the DB resides would be awesome!

Comment: What database engine are you using? How are you connecting to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, try:

```
SHOW variables WHERE `Variable_name` LIKE 'datadir' 
OR `Variable_name` like 'hostname';
```

This shows the host of the server you are connected to as well as the path to the data directory.  Whatever DB you are querying against is whichever one you selected.  It should reside in `%datadir%/%db_name%`

Any other info you may be looking for might be found by showing all variables (`SHOW variables`) or showing status (`SHOW status`).

See also [SHOW Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show.html).

Answer (score 0):

You're using PHP, so you can return `mysql_error` or `mysqli_error` (if you're using the `mysqli` extension).

This will output any error occured during the connection process.